# Showing that $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x< 0, y<0 \}$ is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy > 0 \}$. Show that $A$ is a open subset of the plane.

I have that $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x > 0,y>0 \} \cup \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x< 0, y<0 \}$

Letting $(x,y) \in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x > 0,y>0 \}$ and $r=\min\{x,y\},$$B((x,y), r)$ I have that $$|x-x'| \leqslant \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2} = d((x,y), (x',y')) \leqslant r < \frac{r}{2}$$ so $x' >\frac{r}2 >0.$ Similar reasoning can be done for $y'$. Which would show that $B((x,y),r) \subset \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x > 0,y>0 \}$.

How should I deal with the set $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x< 0, y<0 \}$? I cannot seem to show this... If I let $(x,y) \in \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x< 0, y<0 \}$ and again $r = \min\{x,y\}$ and construct a ball $B((x,y), r)$ I can pick $(x',y') \in B((x,y), r)$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: $r<r/2?$ How? For the second part take $r=\min\{|x|,|y|\}=\min\{-x,-y\}$ and proceed similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer given definitely works, but I will offer a perhaps more "nuts and bolts" type answer.

Let $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y < 0\}$

Fix a point $(x,y) \in D$, and let $\delta = \min\{|x|, |y|\}$

We claim the Ball $B:=B_\delta((x,y))$ of radius $\delta$ centered at $(x,y)$ is contained in $D$.

Let $(s,t) \in B$. We have to show that $s,t < 0$. Since $(s,t) \in B$, we have the $$\sqrt{(s-x)^2 + (t-y)^2} < \delta$$

Note that $$|s-x| = \sqrt{(s-x)^2} \leq \sqrt {(s-x)^2 + (t-y)^2} < \delta $$

Since $|s-x| < \delta$, we have $-\delta < s-x < \delta \iff -\delta + x < s < \delta + x$

But $\delta + x \leq |x| + x = -x + x = 0$ where we have used the fact that $|x| = -x$ since $x < 0$.

This immediately tells us $s < 0$. Showing $t < 0$  is similar.

Hence, $(s,t) \in D \implies B \subset D$, as desired

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)= xy$ is continuous as a map from $\Bbb R^2 \to R$.

$A = f^{-1}[(0, \rightarrow\rangle]$ is thus open, as the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function.

Comment: What does $f^{-1}[(0, \rightarrow\rangle]$ mean?

Comment: Just take it to mean $f^{-1}((0, \infty))$, i.e. the pre-image of $(0,\infty)$ under $f$.

Comment: This is a nice demonstration. However, from the way he constructs his approach to solving the @OP problem it seems that he is looking for a more elementary proof.

Comment: @EkeshKumar the oreimage of the set $[0,\rightarrow \rangle = \{x \in \Bbb R\mid x>0\}$, a notation I learned in highschool.

Comment: @Alex This *is* elementary. It’s I think how most sets in practice are recognised as being open.